# Oracle SQL - IF/CASE statement to choose a particular inner join

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   AID.INVOICE_ID,
   AID.AMOUNT,
   AID.PERIOD_NAME,
   GCC.SEGMENT1 as Organisation,
   GCC.SEGMENT2,
   GCC.SEGMENT3,
   GCC.SEGMENT4,
   INV.INVOICE_NUM,
   INV.CREATION_DATE,
   PO.SEGMENT1 as PO_Number,
   SUP.VENDOR_NAME,
   AID.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE,
   LINES.LINE_NUMBER
FROM
   AP_INVOICES_All INV 
   INNER JOIN
      AP_INVOICE_LINES_ALL LINES 
      ON INV.INVOICE_ID = LINES.INVOICE_ID 
   INNER JOIN
      AP_INVOICE_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL AID 
      ON INV.INVOICE_ID = AID.INVOICE_ID 
   INNER JOIN
      GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GCC 
      ON AID.DIST_CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID 
   INNER JOIN
      POZ_SUPPLIERS_V SUP 
      ON INV.VENDOR_ID = SUP.VENDOR_ID 
   LEFT JOIN
      PO_HEADERS_ALL PO 
      ON LINES.PO_HEADER_ID = PO.PO_HEADER_ID 
   LEFT JOIN
      PO_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL PDA 
      ON INV.INVOICE_ID = PDA.PO_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL 
WHERE
   AID.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE NOT IN 
   (
      'REC_TAX',
      'NONREC_TAX'
   )
   AND LINES.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE NOT IN 
   (
      'TAX'
   )

END


ORDER BY
   AID.INVOICE_ID,
   LINES.LINE_NUMBER
```

I am looking at something similar to the below. What I want to say is that if PO.SEGMENT is null, then select the columns from a table using the join specified. Use different columns in the join depending on whether PO.SEGMENT is null or not. Is this easily achievable?

```
CASE 

WHEN PO.SEGMENT IS NOT NULL 
THEN SEGMENT1,SEGMENT2,SEGMENT3,SEGMENT4 
FROM GCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID 
WHERE PDA.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID

WHEN PO.SEGMENT IS NULL 
THEN SEGMENT1,SEGMENT2,SEGMENT3,SEGMENT4 
FROM GCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID 
WHERE AID.DIST_CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID

END
```

Answer (score 1):

How about rephrasing your logic so that you just have a single `ON` clause:

```
ON
    (PO.SEGMENT IS NOT NULL AND PDA.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID) OR
    (PO.SEGMENT IS NULL AND AID.DIST_CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID)
```

I left out the other details of the rest of your query, but I suggest this because it may be possible to achieve what you want with careful logic.

Comment: This is a good approach, although I would add that the entire ON statement needs to be wrapped in parenthesis otherwise you may leave an OR statement that will cause a cartesian product.